# Selenium How to activate an element that returns false on click, and sendkeys does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, css, selenium

I have read all the posts on this and tried all of the solutions plus a few from selenium HQ yet I still get the same result.  The click event fires or send keys goes and no error yet the pop up which should appear does not.
Website code First Div is parent to subsequent Divs:

```
<div id="27c16ba3-04f0-e711-8103-3863bb35cc58_userName" class="userName">
<a href="#" onclick="Wall.Control.Utils.WindowUtils.openObject(8,'b0b26cd5-1d84-e711-8109-e0071b66cfb1');
    return false;"
    title="Consultant">Consultant
</a>
</div> 
<div class="postActionsWrapper">
<a id="likeaction_27c16ba3-04f0-e711-8103-3863bb35cc58" 
    href="#" class="textAction " 
    title="Like this post" 
    onmouseup="dispatchWallCommand(this, 'likeaction', $P_CRM(this).tmplItem().data);
    return false;
    " onclick="return false;
    " onkeydown="var keycode = (window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13 || keycode == 32){dispatchWallCommand(this, 'likeaction', $P_CRM(this).tmplItem().data); 
    return false;}"> LIKE 
</a>
<span class="separatorAction">|</span>
<a id="commentaction_27c16ba3-04f0-e711-8103-3863bb35cc58" 
    href="#" class="textAction " 
    title="Comment on this post" 
    onmouseup="dispatchWallCommand(this, 'commentaction', $P_CRM(this).tmplItem().data); 
    return false;
    " onclick="return false;
    " onkeydown="var keycode = (window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13 || keycode == 32){dispatchWallCommand(this, 'commentaction', $P_CRM(this).tmplItem().data); 
    return false;}"> REPLY          
</a>
<a id="deleteaction_27c16ba3-04f0-e711-8103-3863bb35cc58" 
    href="#" 
    class="imageAction lastAction" 
    title="Delete this post" 
    onmouseup="dispatchWallCommand(this, 'deleteaction', $P_CRM(this).tmplItem().data); 
    return false;
    " onclick="return false;
    " onkeydown="var keycode = (window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which); 
    if(keycode == 13 || keycode == 32){dispatchWallCommand(this, 'deleteaction', $P_CRM(this).tmplItem().data); 
    return false;}">            
    <img src="/{636500878720000136}/WebResources//msdyn_/Images/actions_delete.png?ver=0" alt="Delete this post" border="0">              
</a>
</div>
```

And here are some of the things I have tried to get this to work.

```
public static void HoverOverAndClick(IWebDriver browser, By by)
{
        Actions action = new Actions(browser);
        IWebElement invisibleElement = browser.FindElement(by);
        action.MoveToElement(invisibleElement).Perform();
        /*
        if(IsTheElementVisible(invisibleElement))
        { action.Click(invisibleElement); }
        else //The method below is not the recommended path but it was the only one I found that worked
        {
            String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript(js, invisibleElement);
            action.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }*/
        //String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject){ arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
        String onClickScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('click',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject){ arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');}";
        String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript(js, invisibleElement);
       // Thread.Sleep(3000);
       // ((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript(mouseOverScript, invisibleElement);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript(onClickScript, invisibleElement);
    }//end hover over
```

Any one with a guess as to what I could try next?  Because all that is occurring to me is to try and get at the DOM directly, and that seems like it would be wasteful of time and effort.

Comment: Please post a link to the site. Also, the first DIV is not the parent of subsequent DIVs. It is closed on the 6th line. You never indicated which link you are trying to click. Your variable name in `HoverOverAndClick()` indicates an invisible element. If it truly is invisible, Selenium will not click it (but will throw an error). How do you know you have the right locator for the element? Why do you need to hover the element before clicking it? Have you tried just clicking it?

Comment: If you are required to hover then click, have you verified that the element you hover is in fact the same element that you need to click?

Comment: @jeffc The element is made visible by the js injection , see string js in the code.  I can watch watch the browser to see that the element becomes visible.  As a matter of fact the linkis visible for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I found that the below code works for the MS CRM application I am testing.

```
       if(IsTheElementVisible(element))
        { action.Click(element); }
        else //The method below is not the recommended path but it was the only one I found that worked.  Directly manipulating the CSS is usually considered a no no.  I should have used Selenum to fake a mouse action but that did not work so...
        {
            browser.ExecuteScript($"document.getElementById('{element}').setAttribute('style', 'display: inline;')");
            element.Click();
        }
```

OHH and you will need to do a thread sleep upon return to the calling function.  For some reason I do not know or understand, waituntil, and thread sleep in the function that makes the element visible and clicks on it to get the input text box does not yield the expected results.

Comment: The code I put in above should not work but it does     '          public static void HoverOverAndClick(IWebDriver browser, By by)
        {
            Actions action = new Actions(browser);
            IWebElement elem = browser.FindElement(by);
            action.MoveToElement(elem).Perform();
            if(IsTheElementVisible(elem))
            { action.Click(elem); }
            else 
            {
                browser.ExecuteScript($"document.getElementById('{elem.GetAttribute("Id")}').setAttribute('style', 'display: inline;')");
                elem.Click();}}'